# UIDocumentInteractionController not working for ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c

UIDocumentInteractionController is not showing on ipad mini , but it working for all other devices.

Here is my code:

```
interactionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];

if (![interactionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:viewController.view.window animated:YES])
    NSLog(@"Failed to show Open In menu");
    [Logger printLog:@"Log file is created"];
```

Comment: I have the same (or similar) problem, in all devices work, but on my iPad mini 1, it appears and suddenly dissapears...